# Jquery to replace all images with same name

Tags: jquery

I have couple of  tags which has same "name" attribute. Something like this:

```
<img name="pic1" src="" />
<img name="pic1" src="" />
<img name="pic1" src="" />
```

Now, I would like to replace the src of all images which has same "name". How can I do this using Jquery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI: the `name` attribute isn't valid for the `<img>` element, so your HTML will not validate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should not use the `name` attribute on images. Instead, use the `class` attribute.

Then you would do something like this:

```
$('img.someClassName').attr('src', '/images/foo.jpg');
```

If you would want to check the current source, you would have to take another approach:

```
$('img.someClassName').each(function() {
    // let's say we only want to alter the src
    // for images of ponies
    if ($(this).attr('src') == '/images/ponies.jpg') {
        // awesome pony detection algorithm triggered!
        $(this).attr('src', '/images/unicorn.jpg');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I check for the exsisting src?

Comment: You can also pass a function to `attr` instead of using `each`, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991693/jquery-to-replace-all-images-with-same-name/5991726#5991726) for an example.

Comment: @Andy nice one, had not seen that syntax yet!

Answer (score 1):

Use a class name instead, to keep your HTML valid:

```
<img class="pic1" src="" />
<img class="pic1" src="" />
<img class="pic1" src="" />
```

```javascript
$(function () {
    $("img.pic1").attr('src', 'myimg.png');
});
```

You can also pass a function to `attr` to give each `<img>` element a different src:

```
 $("img.pic1").attr('src', function (index, oldVal) {
     if (oldVal == "default-img.png")
         this.src = "img"+index+".png";
     else
         this.src = "default-img.png";
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

name isnt valid html attrib for image tag, but the following may still work.

```
$().ready(function(){
  $('img[name="pic1"]').attr('src','new-src-value')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').each(function() {
    $('img[name="'+this.getAttribute('name')+'"]').attr('src',newSrc);
});
```

This is a method of changing all occurrences of any name

Comment: Why not `$(this).attr('src', newSrc);`?  Running a selector like that for each img element isn't going to be very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('img[name=pic1]').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/50x50');
});
```

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/gLR2J/) on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `name` tag with a `class` tag, and use something like this:

```
$('img.pic1').each(function(){
    this.src = 'new source';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img[name="pic1"]').attr('src', 'location.png');
```

I think the above will definitely work :)